# Sync Firebase Realtime Database to result of API endpoint

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm writing a script to sync results from an API with a specific child in the Firebase Realtime Database, but I cannot think of a way to approach this. Do I create a reference for every child of every endpoint (~100,000 references total), or do I merely keep a reference to the entire object, compare the two, and push the differences. If the latter is the better approach, would there be a way for me to access Firebase's local cache (I'm using the Firebase Admin SDK on Node.js), so that I don't have to download the entire database on start?

Here is an example to illustrate what I mean:

Let's take the following endpoint [`https://api.vexdb.io/get_events`](https://api.vexdb.io/get_events).  It returns an array of objects, all with a property know as an `SKU`, which is a unique ID which will serve as the primary key/parent key in the Firebase Realtime Database. Given this data, I transform it into one big object with keys that all point to one of the original indexes of the array. I want to sync this object into the Database. Does that clarify?

Comment: From your question, it's not completely clear what it is that you want to do, but it sounds like you could use a single reference and use [`on`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#on) to listen to the `child_changed` event. That won't see all of the data downloaded, but will see you informed of any changed children. You might also want the `child_removed` event, but your question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I'm mobile, so it's a little hard to be more specific, but here I go. I have an API which updates every few minutes. I am trying to download that data periodically, apply a few transformations to get it in regulation with my firebase database, and push any changes to the database. I'll amend my post with an example